# How can I remotely send commands to Tasker or other automation?

Tags: tasker, automation

I'm looking for a way of sending remote commands to Tasker on my Android TV. Specifically, I'm trying to find a way to trigger an HTTP GET request from IFTTT to Tasker or another automation app (like Automate) which would execute a command locally on the TV.

Is there any way to do this in Tasker, Automate or another automation app?

Comment: There's an app called pushbullet that may be of help. You might have to do a bit more programming of tasker but it might do the job

Comment: Automate has the Cloud message blocks, for device-to-device and web-to-device communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best app I've found to send a remote command from one android device to another is going to be [AutoRemote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoremote), a tasker plug in, but this assumes you android tv devices has access to the play store. This app should also work well for you if you have tasker because you can [directly integrate it into IFTTT](https://joaoapps.com/autoremote/ifttt/). By integrating directly with IFTTT it removes the issues you'll likely have trying to use an http get request.